# How do I make peace between the Quarians and the Geth?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have an imported save from ME1 and 2.

- I've saved Legion,
- Tali was not exiled,
- I destroyed the heretics,
- I brokered a peace between Tali and Legion,
- I completed *Rannoch: Admiral Koris* and saved Admiral Koris
- I have 4 bars of Paragon

However, I still don't get the option to be able to make peace between the Geth and the Quarians.

Comment: I think you have to choose "allow the upload", sending you down the road to the geth winning and the quarians dying, to get the option to make peace. If you deny the upload you go straight to the quarians winning and the geth dying without getting the option to make peace. Also you have to do Legion's sidequest on Rannoch (the one where you "enter the matrix").

Comment: By the first question you have to choose allow upload. In theory after that Tali asks the admirals to cease fire. If she was not exiled and you have enough reputation then you can talk to the admiral to do so. After that you need a loyal Legion and you need to upload the code. I did not manage by my second playthrough, probably because Tali was exiled, so they did not listen to her. By my first playthrough it was okay. I am not sure what I did different, the first was two years ago.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple but rep must be 100 percent doesn't matter how much of each but i had full paragon so that says otherwise when ever legion ask after defeating the reaper if he should upgrade the geth answer yes and later a paragon/renegade will pop up do either and you will stop the general from harming the geth then legion will upgrade them but die sadly